Why does magnetic susceptibility increase until Neel temperature in antiferromagnetic materials?
The following figure (from this paper) shows typical behavior of an antiferromagnet's susceptibility with respect to temperature. The susceptibility starts at a non-zero value and increases until the cusp at the Neel temperature $T_N$ before entering the paramagnetic phase and decreasing.
My understanding is that, below $T_N$, we have long-range order with antiferromagnetic alignment of spins, and that above $T_N$, we enter a disordered paramagnetic state in which long-range order is destroyed but short-range antiferromagnetic order may persist.
What I don't understand is why the susceptibility increases when considering the region between $0K$ and $T_N$. Does it have something to do with thermal energy? Any advice and sources would be appreciated!

